# Optimize postgres query avg by month [edited]

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

We have this table that save prices many times a day and we need to get the avg price of each day by month..

basically, we filter those prices based on code and date and use `UNION` for each month

Table example:

| date | code | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 'FS-H21' | 150 |
| 2020-01-01 | 'FS-H21' | 151 |
| 2020-01-01 | 'FS-G21' | 155 |
| 2020-01-02 | 'FS-H21' | 151 |
| 2020-01-03 | 'FS-G21' | 148 |

and the query example:

```sql
SELECT period, code, avg(price)
FROM period_prices
WHERE code = 'FS-F21' AND period BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
GROUP BY period, code

UNION

SELECT period, code, avg(closure)
FROM period_prices
WHERE code = 'FS-F21' AND period BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29'
GROUP BY period, code

...
```

Reproduced table and query at [sample query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/315889/1)...

**EDIT:**

desired result:

`FS-H21` had 3 prices stored every day. report must show the average price for that code on every day in a specific period, like in one month (`BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'`)

Table:

| date | code | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 'FS-H21' | 150 |
| 2020-01-01 | 'FS-H21' | 151 |
| 2020-01-01 | 'FS-H21' | 152 |
| 2020-01-03 | 'FS-H21' | 150 |
| 2020-01-03 | 'FS-H21' | 152 |
| 2020-01-04 | 'FS-H21' | 155 |

Query result:
| date | code | avg |
| -- | -- | --|
| 2020-01-01 |  'FS-H21' |  151 |
| 2020-01-04 |  'FS-H21' |  151 |
| 2020-01-05 |  'FS-H21' |  155 |

I would like some advice on how can i improve the performance of that query, or if there is a better way to achieve this!

thanks

Comment: What results do you want?  There is no reason to write separate queries if you just want to aggregate by day.

Comment: i edited the question, 
i need to get avg prices of each day of each month in between one/two years...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you want to aggregate by *month*, not by *day*.  That would be:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', period) as yyyymm, code, avg(closure)
FROM period_prices
WHERE code = 'FS-F21' 
GROUP BY yyyymm, code;
```

If you want the average for every day, then you can just use a single query:

```
SELECT period, code, avg(closure)
FROM period_prices
WHERE code = 'FS-F21' 
GROUP BY period, code;
```